# Aggregate averages of MySQL data fails

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table filled with data on cars sold.

I would like to get daily averages so im am using aggregation and the below function.

```
SELECT
        DAYOFMONTH(TIMESTAMP) AS DAY,
        MONTH(TIMESTAMP) AS MONTH,
        AVG(number_sold) AS sold,
        AVG(amount_earned) AS earned,
        AVG(wages_spent) AS wages
FROM cardata
GROUP BY DAYOFMONTH(TIMESTAMP)
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC
LIMIT 0, 12;
```

I should get 12 rows with 1 row for each day. The 12 rows returns but problem getting a row for each day I.e. for February I only get the 5th and the 8th day.

Is there something wrong with my statement?

Help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the GROUPBY is not right here.

Try:

```
GROUP BY DAYOFMONTH( TIMESTAMP ) , MONTH( TIMESTAMP )
```

This should group the data how you need it.

Alternatively you could do something like:

```
SELECT
   DATE_FORMAT ( TIMESTAMP, '%m/%d' ) AS DAY,
   ...
FROM cardata
GROUP BY DAY
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC
LIMIT 0, 12
```

But fixing the GROUPBY is the main thing that should fix it.

Comment: hey thanks the groupby fixed it, did not realise I could do that